# NULL coalescing Dictonary lookup

Tags: c#, collections

One thing that always bugs me is how many lines of code it takes to do this very simple (and for my work, very common) operation:

```
  var lTheDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  // The dictionary gets some stuff put in it elsewhere...

  // Do annoying lookup that must be common but is always unwieldy.
  object lTheObject;
  int lTheValue; // NOTE: Not always an int
  if (lTheDict.TryGetValue("TheKey", out lTheObject))
  {
    lTheValue = (int) lTheObject;
  }
```

I'm sure there must be a better way to do this, perhaps with null coalescing or something. What I'd really like to be able to write is something like:

```
  int lTheValue ?= (int) lTheDict["TheKey"];
```

In other words, if TheKey exists, get me the value, otherwise just give me the "empty" int.

It's almost impossible to shave lines off. Even if we just attempt the lookup-and-cast and catch the exception on a single line catch-and-ignore (none of which are permitted by my workplace code style), we'd *still* have to declare the variable outside the try block, and end up with something like:

```
  int lTheValue;
  try {
    lTheValue = (int) lTheDict["TheKey"];
  } catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Which is again a ridiculous amount of overhead code masking what should be a pretty obvious operation.

Even just to be able to get rid of the declaration of lTheObject by declaring it at the point where we use it as an outparam (which is coming in .NET 5 or something I hear) would remove one line. The functions where this lives are often only 10 lines long themselves, and it looks like we're doing something important with this collection because half of the code is devoted to just getting out a value, but really it's just a distraction.

**NOTE:** I know I can write a templated function to do it, but even in the function it's going to annoy me having to write these lines AGAIN. There must be a better way!

Has anyone found, or can you think of, a shorter way to write this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cs
static class MyExtensions
{
   public static T MagicGet<T>(
       this Dictionary<string, object> lookup,
       string key)
   {
       return lookup.TryGetValue(key, out var value)) ? (T)value : default(T);
   }
}
...
var value = lTheDict.MagicGet<int?>("TheKey");
```

Or without creating an extension, you can simply write your original lookup like this:

```
  int lTheValue = lTheDict.TryGetValue("TheKey", out object lTheObject) ? (int) lTheObject : default(int);
```

Comment: Not bad! And very speedy response. I had not considered an extension. I will hold off marking you as the answer until I see what other options people come up with.

Comment: I notice you declared the var value in the parameters. I just went to check because I did not think you could do that in .NET 4 (and hence not in dotnetcore 2.0), but you can, at least in dotnetcore 2.0. So thanks at least for showing me that!

Comment: @DerfSkren `var` is a compiler feature, not a runtime feature - it works on any target as long as you're using a compiler that has the feature

Comment: it's not the `var` part it's that you've declared the outparam at the point where you are using it. That has not always been possible.

Comment: @DerfSkren oh, indeed; but again: compiler feature, not runtime

Answer (score 1):

I have these two extension method defined in most of my code:

```
public static Func<K, V> Map<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> source, Func<V> @default)
{
    return key => (key == null || !source.ContainsKey(key)) ? @default() : source[key];
}

public static Func<K, V> Map<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> source, Func<K, V> @default)
{
    return key => (key == null || !source.ContainsKey(key)) ? @default(key) : source[key];
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
Dictionary<string, object> lTheDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

Func<string, object> mapTheDict = lTheDict.Map(k => (int?)null);

object lTheValue = mapTheDict("TheKey");
```

The interesting thing here is that you can use the lambda to return a default value that is based on the key itself. I find that very useful - especially for debugging.

Comment: That is a great additional feature! Thanks for your response.